# Vector Element Size

Tags: c++, vector, int, size

For the following code, `vv[1].size()` will return an output of 4. I was wondering where this number came from.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> vv;
    vector<int> v1(3,5);
    vector<int> v2(4,7);
    vv.push_back(v1);
    vv.push_back(v2);
    cout << vv.size() << endl << vv[1].size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you are a beginner, see this [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10147399)

Comment: `v2(4,7)` creates a vector of 4 elements all with the value of `7`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `vector<int> v2(4,7);` creates a vector of size 4 whose values are all 7. You most likely meant to write `vector<int> v2 {4,7};` which creates a vector with 2 elements of 4 and 7.

Comment: [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you can find a complete list of constructors of `std::vector`

Comment: The code was actually a practice problem where I was supposed to write the output.  I think I'm having trouble grasping `vector<vector<int>> vv` . Why is vv[1] v2?

Comment: Ah I see, that is because vv is a vector of vectors. "push_back" adds the vector you created to the vector of vectors. At the end of the program, vv will look like this:
[[5, 5, 5],[7,7,7,7]]. [5,5,5] is the first vector created as v1, [7,7,7,7] is the second created as v2.

Comment: Size and number of elements are different. You can pre-allocate memory for a vector and show a rather lengthy size even though there are no valid elements within the vector. When you run over the Pre-alllocation amount, it typically increments in powers of two unless you change the re-size granularity for the data structure